# How make 3d text in three js

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, three.js

I write a script by referencing [this doc](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) and [this doc](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/TextGeometry.js)
 my code is

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
   <script> 
   var text = "my text",

            height = 20,
            size = 70,
            hover = 30,

            curveSegments = 4,

            bevelThickness = 2,
            bevelSize = 1.5,
            bevelSegments = 3,
            bevelEnabled = true,

            font = "optimer", // helvetiker, optimer, gentilis, droid sans, droid serif
            weight = "bold", // normal bold
            style = "normal"; // normal italic
   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
   var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {

                size: size,
                height: height,
                curveSegments: curveSegments,

                font: font,
                weight: weight,
                style: style,

                bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
                bevelSize: bevelSize,
                bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled,


            });


//  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,10,1);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x11ff00});
  var textGeo = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, material); 
  scene.add(textGeo);
  camera.position.z = 10;
  function render() { 
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      textGeo.rotation.x += 0.01;
      textGeo.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera); 
 } 


 render();


</script>
```

i can make cube and other geometry by changing the code slightly. But i cant make 3d text
using this script.
whats the problem with this code? 
[image: my error in console is] please help me

Comment: this is error 
TypeError: this.faces[this.face] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

return this.faces[ this.face ][ this.weight ][ this.style ];

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to load a font file using a pattern like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

    // your code here

} );
```

See, for example, this three.js example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html

Also, I'd advise against assigning the same variable name to both your geometry and your mesh.

three.js r.128

Comment: Note the standard is now json: `loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', ..`

Comment: @bebbi Thank you. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

I also wrote [this tutorial](http://blog.andrewray.me/creating-a-3d-font-in-three-js/) on creating a 3d font, since I hit a few gotchas that I thought were worth documenting.